# How to implement tree like structure in mysql and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-design

A question struck in my mind for 2 days and wondering whether it is possible to implement this type of tree structure in laravel and MySQL.

[image]

(First, take a look at the image attached. Thanks)

Suppose our platform uses refer system, and initially, a user 'A' join. Now, this user 'A' further refers 3 persons 'B','C','D'. Now, the total refer on A is 3 (because it refers 3 persons).

Now, let B further refers 'E','F' and 'C' further refers 'G','H', 'I' and 'D' refers 0. So, now refer of each person is "D = 0", "C = 3", "B = 2". and these refers will also add up on "A". So, it has "A = 8".

Now, 'G' refers 'J', so 'G' gets +1 and 'C' also gets +1 and 'C' is referred by 'A', so 'A' also gets +1. Now, total refer to each person is : 
"j = 0","G=1","H=0","I=0", "D=0","E=0","f=0","B=2","C=4 (beacuse G refers J also)","A=9(beacuase 9 childers are refered by him)"

The chain continues until A gets total refer of 40.

In simple, if a person refers another person then it will get +1 and it's parent whom he gets refer also get +1 and so on until parent reaches 40, the chain continues.

I know, this is One-Many relationship between a user and refer and we can use a pivot table, but, How can we implement this type of logic. Give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a pivot table, I would just add a `referred_by` column in the same table. Where would you like to put this logic? Do you want a function that would calculate the number of people a given user has referred or something like that?

Comment: that means we need to use while loop on referred_by and keep on going until referred_by reaches null?

Comment: I Just want to know how to implement this type of logic, and if it is possible I want to develop it.

Comment: The way to do it would be to run a query to select all the "children" of a given user, and then continually run where in queries of the returned users to select their "children" until you get a query that yields no results. Then it would be a case of counting the number of "children" and "children of children" in total. Personally, I would implement it as a recursive method, but you could do it in a loop if you wanted to as well.

Comment: I have added an answer, hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Search for "parent_id".  There are many examples of a single table where each row links to its parent via this extra column.  (Your `A` would have `NULL` or `0` in `parent_id`.)

Answer (score 1):

I have written out something that should hopefully help you with this, using a `while` loop.

```
public function totalReferredBy(User $user)
{
    // Initialise the queue to contain only the provided user
    $queue = collect([$user]);

    // This collection will eventually contain all of the "child"/referred users
    $results = collect();

    while ($queue->isNotEmpty() > 0) {
        // Run a where in query to select all the referred users of the users in the queue.
        $referredUsers = User::whereIn('referred_by', $queue->pluck('id'))->get();

        // Merge the referredUsers we have found in the database with the results collection, so we can later count.
        $results = $results->merge($referredUsers);

        // Make the referredUsers we have just found in the database, the new queue. If the query did not return any
        // referred users, the queue count would be 0 and the loop will exit.
        $queue = $referredUsers;
    }

    // Now we should have all of the given user's "children" and "children of children" in the $results collection.
    // We just need to return the count of that collection to get the total number of users that have been referred.
    return $results->count();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$totalReferred = $this->totalReferredBy($user);
```

Then if your application does something when the user reaches 40 or more referred, you can just do:

```
if ($this->totalReferredBy($user) > 40) {
    // Do something
}
```

This assumes that you have a `referred_by` column on the `users` table.